# Cloud Endpoints won't require authentication

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I've built a custom endpoints API with Google App Engine that communicates with a web client, and I've successfully tested it with the API explorer and the web client.

Now I'm trying to add authentication to the cloud endpoints API via these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/auth), using [web client ID](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth#Creating_a_web_client_ID).  I can get authentication to work, but can't get the authentication to be *required*.

```
WEB_CLIENT_ID = # Some Client ID

@endpoints.api(name="AppApi", version="v1", allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID], audiences=[WEB_CLIENT_ID], scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE])
class AppApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(TestRequestMessage, TestResponseMessage, name="test.get", path="test/get")
    def TestGet(self, request):
        response = TestResponseMessage()
        # Return a blank response message
        return response
```

I'm purposely trying to exclude `endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID` in the `allowed_client_ids`, because I want to make sure it will fail for requests that are not being authenticated with the API Explorer.

When I go to the API explorer though, I can make successful requests *without* authentication.  When I turn on authentication with the API explorer, it asks me to enable the email authentication, so that works, but it doesn't require authentication for calls.

How do you get the Google Cloud Endpoints API to require authentication for every call?

I'm also not doing any User specific work with the API, so I'm just trying to use web-client authentication using web client credentials, so that it's the web client requesting information.  There are no user logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two auth layers to think about when dealing with endpoints:

- The Client ID layer, which manages what code from where, with what Client ID/secrets can call the API. You can read about this [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).
- The User auth layer, which manages an OAuth2.0 For Login/OpenID Connect (same thing) process in which a user grants `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope to the application, and the application sends a Bearer token along with each API request, so that the endpoint server can use that token to fetch the profile info of the user on whose behalf the request was made. You can read more about the User auth layer of endpoints in the docs ([java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth)/[python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth))

Your issue, if I understand your post, relates to the fact that you can make API Explorer requests even if the API Explorer's Client ID is not in the list of allowed IDs. This is a known issue which I believe has been mentioned in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) and thus is being worked on, probably with a high priority.

At the very least, knowing that it's not a result of your own error should let you be at ease and continue developing, knowing that it'll be fixed relatively soon, and doesn't represent a risk to security, since only you can access the API Explorer for your own project.

Comment: So authorization with endpoints for a web client still requires user-layer authentication? What if I just want to make sure that only the web app client is connecting to endpoints, but don't want to have to bother the individual user to log in or authorize?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to figure it out.  I needed to use `endpoints.get_current_user() != None` (python) to validate each call that there is indeed a user who authorized the current call.  There doesn't appear to be a way to authorize endpoint calls with just an application, without using the OAuth from the user.  It would be nice if there was a way to say "Only allow calls from this application" with endpoints, but this works for now.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm glad you figured out how to do user auth without me coming back,  as I had read your comment earlier but couldn't sit down to write. As far as your most recent comment, it's not true to say there's now way to do calling-context auth - that's exactly what client ID/secrets are for. User auth is for whether you want to check that an OAuth2 for Login user account authorized your app to have userinfo.email scope, and has a valid Bearer token sent along with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Endpoints will not automatically enable authentication by itself. Via the annotations, you have marked the API method for secure access.

What you will have to do for each call is to check the User object and determine if :

- It is a valid user
- Do your own authorization checks for the user

If it does not meet your authentication and authorization requirements, you should have the appropriate logic to return the correct HTTP Error code or some other data if it is anonymous sort of access.

In the instructions, this is specific as the 3rd point : "Add a current user check (endpoints.get_current_user) to each method you wish to protect."

Comment: This is not a correct answer for the question asked, but what you say regarding User auth is correct. Endpoints has two layers of authentication. There's the Client ID auth layer, and there's the User auth layer. OP is asking why the API Explorer can still make requests when the API Explorer Client ID is not in the list of allowed Client IDs.